# Initialization problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem.
This is my code.
When i try to use the IBAction SavePosition the "arrayPosition" isn't update.
Else if i initialize the "arrayPosition" in "SavePosition" the value is stored in the array.
Why this anomaly?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AccelerometroViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>{

    //.....     

    NSMutableArray *arrayPosizioni;
    NSMutableArray *arrayPosizioniCorrenti;

    NSString *nomePosizioneCorrente;

}

-(IBAction)salvaPosizione;


//...
@property (nonatomic, assign)   NSMutableArray      *arrayPosizioni;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   NSMutableArray      *arrayPosizioniCorrenti;

@property (nonatomic, assign)   NSString      *nomePosizioneCorrente;

@end



#import "AccelerometroViewController.h"
#import "Position.h"

@implementation AccelerometroViewController



float actualX;
float actualY;
float actualZ;


@synthesize arrayPosition;
@synthesize arrayCurrentPosition;

@synthesize nameCurrentPosition;

    -(id)init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self != nil) {
            arrayPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            arrayCurrentPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            nameCurrentPosition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"noPosition"]; 
            actualX = 0;
            actualY = 0;
            actualZ = 0;
        }
        return self;
    }


    -(void)updateTextView:(NSString*)nomePosizione
    {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameCurrentPosition];
        textEvent.text = [textEvent.text        stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        textEvent.text = [textEvent.text        stringByAppendingString:string];
    }


    -(IBAction)savePosition{

        Posizione *newPosition;
        newPosition = [[Position alloc]init];

        if([newPosition     setValue:(NSString*)fieldNomePosizione.text:(float)actualX:(float)actualY:(float)actualZ]){
       //setValue is a method of Position. I'm sure that this method is correct
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView  alloc] initWithTitle:@"Salvataggio Posizione" message:@"Posizione salvata con successo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert  show];
            [alert  release];           
            [arrayPosition  addObject:newPosition];
        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView  alloc] initWithTitle:@"Salvataggio osizione" message:@"Errore nel salvataggio" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
   }
```

Comment: hi. you've got a memory leak in savePosition! You need to release newPosition at the end (or autorelease it when you alloc/init it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Whats going on?**

I bet you're creating your view controller inside a xib file?

If you set a breakpoint inside your init method on the line

```
arrayPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I bet it never runs. This means that when you get to the  line

```
[arrayPosition  addObject:newPosition];
```

arrayPosition is still `nil` so nothing happens.

**How to fix it?**

If you're initializing a UIViewController it's either called inside initWithNibName:bundle: if you've created it in code or in initWithCoder: if it's created inside a xib file.

You need to do something like this :

```
- (void) initialise {
    arrayPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayCurrentPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    nameCurrentPosition = @"noPosition"; 
    actualX = 0;
    actualY = 0;
    actualZ = 0;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle]) {
        [self initialise];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
        [self initialise];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This will call initailise regardless of how the view controller is created.

Comment: i have a warning in "initWithCoder"
warning:control reaches end of non-void function.
If compile with warning the app crash

Comment: Oops, I've fixed it in my answer; I had forgotten to return self;' at the end!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[newPosition setValue:(NSString*)fieldNomePosizione.text:(float)actualX:(float)actualY:(float)actualZ]
```

... is gibberish. I don't even see how it compiles. I assume its a typo. However, if the function does not return a boolean it will return a void pointer and always evaluate to false so the block is never called.

More generally, your problem is most likely that you are not using the `self.propertyName` notation to refer to your properties so they are not being retained. E.g.

```
[arrayPosition  addObject:newPosition];
```

should be:

```
[self.arrayPosition  addObject:newPosition];
```

... as should all other references to `arrayPosition` in the code.

Comment: Hi TechZen, the question states that if arrayPosition is initialized inside the method, the data gets saved so we can assume that the method 'setValue' does return YES ;) Also, in the init method the arrays are declared using alloc] init] which will retain them. If they were being declared and not retained we'd probably see an exception :) You're right about good practice using self.arrayPosition though - that's definitely the right thing to do.